# How can I create a unique dataframe containing all the statistics for each stock?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a unique data frame for all the items in the ticker list. The data frame should include the 67 fields extracted from yahoo with the pandas_datareader. The data frame index (or the first columns) should ideally be the ticker itself.

I have tried to run the code below, using the method df.append or df.concat, but I always get the error:

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ""; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

Could anyone suggest the right code to merge the data frames for the 3 tickers in a single data frame?

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr

tickers = ['AMZN', 'AAPL', 'O']
dataset_list = pd.DataFrame()

for ticker in tickers:
    stats = pdr.get_quote_yahoo(ticker)
    for row in stats:
        dataset_list.concat(row, ignore_index = True)
dataset_list
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
tickers = ['AMZN', 'AAPL', 'O']
dataset_list = pd.DataFrame()
for ticker in tickers:
    stats = pdr.get_quote_yahoo(ticker)
    dataset_list = dataset_list.append(stats)
dataset_list = dataset_list.reset_index().rename(columns={"index":"ticker"})
dataset_list
```

```
ticker     ask  askSize averageDailyVolume10Day averageDailyVolume3Month
AMZN    1999.99     8   3503328                      3984588
AAPL    204.49      8   19275700                     27126164
O       70.01       8   1505514                      2024175
```

Comment: Hi tawab, that works perfectly! thanks for your precious help!

Comment: @AnBento great :) if you find it helpful upvote or accept it

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can try to use `pd.concat`

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr

tickers = ['AMZN', 'AAPL', 'O']
df = pd.concat([pdr.get_quote_yahoo(t) for t in tickers])
```